# React: Execute function on website exit, without giving an alert warning

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, addeventlistener, use-effect, onbeforeunload

I have a hook that executes the function passed to it when someone leaves the current page, or when they leave the website

```
const useOnPageLeave = (handler) => {
    useEffect(() => {

        window.onbeforeunload = undefined;
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {             //When they leave the site
            event.preventDefault();                                     // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
            handler();
        });

        return () => {
            handler();                                                 //When they visit another local link
            document.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handler);
        };
    }, []);
};
```

When using **Firefox or Safari**, this alert message appears(only when they leave the site, not when they visit a local link), and I don't want this alert message to show

[image]

---

If I remove the line `event.preventDefault()`, then the `handler` function is not executed, and I need the handler event to be executed

---

[Here is an MRE of the problem](https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/useOnPageLeave)

Comment: are you using React-router for local page navigation?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yeah, this happens on page leave though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const useOnPageLeave = (handler) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.onbeforeunload = () => handler();

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
      handler();
    });

    return () => {
      handler();
      document.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handler);
    };
  });
};
```

Comment: I don't think that this fixes anything

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I did try it out, i'm going to try to post a github mre

Comment: I posted an [MRE](https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/useOnPageLeave). The problem doesn't happen in chrome or edge, so it should be tested out in firefox or safari

Comment: I'm not sure but I recall that in Firefox you should use `event.returnValue = null;` I'll delete the answer since it didn't resolve your issue.

Comment: @Sam I updated the code in the answer, that works for me.

Comment: So it looks like this code works, but in some cases that action cannot be completed in time before leaving the page. I tried to do an `axios` call and it cannot be completed in firefox, although I am able to do a simple task like logging to the console. Chrome has no problem. Keep your answer up if the axios problem can't be solved, because this is still a correct solution, but doesn't work in all contexts

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with using a listener inside of useEffect.

```
const useOnPageLeave = (handler) => {   

    useEffect(() => {
        
    }, []); // useEffect will only get called once on component did mount 
};
```

So You might want to consider trying to take your logic outside of useEffect

or

Adding a useState hook as a listener might be the way to go

```
const useOnPageLeave = (handler) => {

    const [userLeaving, setUserLeaving] = useState(false);        

    useEffect(() => {

       if (userLeaving) handler();
    
    }, [userLeaving]); // useEffect will only get called once on component did mount AND each time userLeaving state updates
};
```

Comment: "// useEffect will only get called once on component did mount " Not exactly true in this context. [Scroll down to "Why did we return a function from our effect?"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). And the code works, but the alert box when you leave is annoying

Comment: Oh I see. My code useEffect will only get called on component did mount because I added an empty list of dependencies []. I haven't needed to use useEffect without that list of dependencies, but it looks like you're using it such as the example so you're a few steps ahead of me. Sorry for not being able to help :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `firefox` and `safari` browsers are showing this message be default. Not much you can do about it. But there is a good news. It seems they are targeting only `beforeunload` event but not `unload`. So you could try to use that.

Here is more info about that: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1304313

Answer (score 0):

You can simply handle the `unload` event on `window`. For example the following code does an HTTP request while the page is being closed:

```js
window.addEventListener('unload', function (event) {
  (async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/my-endpoint')
    console.log(response)
  })()
})
```

Do note however that the use of the `unload` event is discouraged. See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event) for details (TL;DR: it's unreliable, especially on mobile).